# Word application reference from VSTO to net core class library

Tags: c#, .net-core, ms-word, vsto, .net-4.7.2

I developed a VSTO Word add-in and a class library (net 4.7.2) in C#. This add-in sets a variable in the class library with the current word application object and calls methodes of the class library to manipulate word documents. 
All works well.

This week, I converted the class library to net core (referencing the interop.microsoft.office.interop.word) and it compiled successfully. :)
But the VSTO add-in can not set the application.word reference variable in the class library anymore. It‘s not compatible and throws an error.
I tried to get an object of the running Word application from within the class library but Marshal.GetActiveObject is not in net core available.

Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Short answer is no. There is a feature request which is not implemented yet. You can vote it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/757925/please-port-visual-studio-tools-for-office-vsto-to.html)